# Regular expression to fetch username= 'testuserMM' from the string

Tags: java, regex

I tried this regex to capture username

```
highs\(\d+\)\[.*?\]\[\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\]\sftid\(\d+\):\s.
```

It didn't work.

```
<55>Mar 17 12:02:00 forcesss-off [Father][1x91422234][eee][hote] abcd(QlidcxpOulqsf): highs(23455814)[mothers][192.192.21.12] ftid(64322816): oops authentication failed with (http-commo-auth, username='testuserMM' password='********'congratulation-fakem='login' )
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a much simpler regex for that:

```
\busername='([^']+)
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/sL0cD9/1), result is in Group 1.

**REGEX**:

- `\b` - Word boundary
- `username='` - literal string `username='`
- `([^']+)` - A capturing group containing our substring that only contains 1 or more symbols other then a single apostrophe.

**UPDATE**:

Here are 2 ways to get the text you are looking for:

```
String str = "<55>Mar 17 12:02:00 forcesss-off [Father][1x91422234][eee][hote] abcd(QlidcxpOulqsf): highs(23455814)[mothers][192.192.21.12] ftid(64322816): oops authentication failed with (http-commo-auth, username='testuserMM' password='********'congratulation-fakem='login' )";
String res = str.replaceAll(".*\\busername='([^']+)'.*", "$1");
System.out.println(res);

String rx = "(?<=\\busername=')[^']+";
Pattern ptrn = Pattern.compile(rx);
Matcher m = ptrn.matcher(str);
while (m.find()) {
   System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/Syj4Bh)

Comment: Does it work for you? You can also try with a lookbehind if you are using an engine that supports it: `(?<=\busername=')[^']+`.

Comment: I am only looking for value in single apostrophe which is 'testuserMM'. Your regex give me whole value like username='testuserMM'

Comment: Did you try with a lookbehind, in my previous comment? It will get you that value as a whole match.

Comment: ya, I got your point but I was only looking for value which is inside of Username. Is is possible to get only value instead of whole match?

Comment: What is the language/tool you are using it in? Here is a regex - [`(?<=\busername=')[^']+`](https://regex101.com/r/vB4tN4/1) - that matches any number of characters other than `'` *after* `username='`.

Comment: Great, there is a look-behind support, but in Java, you need to escape the ``\`` twice: `(?<=\\busername=')[^']+`. That is good if you use `Matcher` class. You can also try `String res = str.replaceAll(".*\\busername='([^']+)'.*", "$1");`. See [here](http://ideone.com/Syj4Bh).